# Have only certain WCF SVC methods have anonymous access while the others have windows security?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis

I have a WCF SVC endpoint which has windows authentication.

What I would like to do is allow anonymous access to just one method in the SVC and leave the rest with windows authentication.

Can I do this or do I need and entirely different instance of the wcf svc file to be hosted in IIS with anonymous on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need another contract with this particular method. Binding configuration that is used to specify security configuration is set on an endpoint. An endpoint consist of ABC = Address Binding Contract. Hence, you may have multiple svc files that reference same class but point to different contracts.

To sum up, you need additional svc file, additional contract but you may have only one implementation that implements all the contracts.